# PodioFile::upload working on localhost but not on a live server

Tags: php, podio

I am creating a chrome extension that can create a task to Podio using Podio API PHP. Also, it can attach files. This is working perfectly on localhost. But when I uploaded the php files on a live server, I get an error in `PodioFile::upload`, and it says `'PodioServerError'`.

```
$longStringPathAndName = "url_of_image|filename_of_image,url_of_image2|filename_of_image2"
$longArrayPathAndName = explode(",", $longStringPathAndName);
/*Declare the filearray holder */
$strAttachment = array();

/*Loop for every file item */
$xx = 1;
for ($xx = 0; $xx < count($longArrayPathAndName); $xx++) {
  /*split each file item according to pipe (|), to separate the filepath and filename */
  $arrFile = explode("|", $longArrayPathAndName[$xx]);
  /*Temporarily upload the file, place it in $file so we can get the file_id */
  $file = PodioFile::upload($arrFile[0], $arrFile[1]);
  /*Append the new file_id to the filearray holder */
  array_push($strAttachment, $file->file_id);
}
```

Thank you folks! ^_^

**[EDIT] November 8, 2019**

I uploaded the php files on a free webhosting ([000webhost](https://000webhost.com/)) and it works! My problem is, I don't want to use this free hosting because I have already bought a hosting package in Netvirtue. Is there any restriction set by Netvirtue that makes the `PodioFileUpload` unusable?

*To wrap it up:*

1. Code has no problem, working on a localhost and a free hosting.
2. Code
   does not work on my paid hosting (Netvirtue), I don't know if its
   the same on other paid hosting company. Please confirm.
3. Based on this, I hypothesize that there is a setting that restrict the Podio
   API the direct file upload on my server.

Comment: There's nothing in this code that's related to chrome extensions. Consider removing the tag.